# Grouping of data inside the table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i have a code like this

```
<table>
            <tr>
            <th> Subject </th>
            <th> Description </th>
            <th> Units </th>
            <th> Prerequisite Subject</th>
            </tr>
<?php
$dep = $_SESSION['course'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!$con){
        die('Could not connect to database' .mysql_error());
        }
        else{
        mysql_select_db("enrollment", $con);
        }       
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsubject where department='$dep' order by year asc, semester asc ");
        if(!$result){
        die('Invalid query:' .mysql_error());
        }
        else{
        $cur_year= '';
        $cur_semester = '';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        if($cur_year !== $row['year'] or $cur_semester !== $row['semester']){
        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td colspan="7" align="center"><b>'.$row['year'].'</b></td>';
        echo'</tr>';
        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td colspan="7" align="center"><b>'.$row['semester'].' Semester</b></td>';
        echo'</tr>';

        $cur_year = $row['year'];
        $cur_semester = $row['semester'];

        $sequel = "select sum(units) as sum_value from tblsubject where department='$dep' and year='$cur_year' and semester='$cur_semester' order by year asc, semester asc";
        $results = mysql_query($sequel);

        $cur_unit= '';

        while($rrr = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
        if($cur_unit!== $row['units']){
        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td colspan="7" align="right"><b>Total Of : '.$rrr['sum_value'].' Units</b></td>';
        echo'</tr>'; 

        $cur_unit = $rrr['sum_value'];
        }
        } 
        }

        echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['sub_code'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['sub_desc'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['units'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['prereq'].'</td>';
        echo'</tr>';

        }
        }

?>  
        </table>
```

i have an output like this.

```
| Subject | Description | Units | Prerequisite Subject|
|                   First Year                        |
|                First Semester                       |
|                 Total Units : 3 Units               |
|  IT111  | IT Major    |   3   |      none           |
```

what i want to put the total units at the bottom of listed subjects in every semester.

must be like this.

```
| Subject | Description | Units | Prerequisite Subject|
|                   First Year                        |
|                First Semester                       |
|  IT111  | IT Major    |   3   |      none           |
|                 Total Units : 3 Units               |
```

Because if I put the code of total units below for calculating the units the total will output after every single subject that is added.

Answer (score 0):

The use of mysql is depreciated and you should look into using PDO or mysqli, both of which have statements to return the number of rows. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php for mysqli and https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php for PDO.

If you do still want to use MySQL there is mysql_num_rows.

Once you get your head around PDO you should have no problems with it.